# Hide form when value from dropdown is chosen

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these forms.

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, "Type of home", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

I want when I choose certain value from dropdown to hide the form with RoomsNumber. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what type has model.RoomsNumber? Is it List<int> ? And you have custom editor for model.RoomsNumber? If yes - please post layout of that editor

Comment: no it is not List, it is just integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easyly using JavaScript, you need an **ID** for your **rooms form** and another **ID** for the **product category drop down list**, then you need add an **event listener** to hear the **change event** of your drop down:

**JS**

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlProductCategory'),
    form = document.getElementById('roomsForm');

ddl.addEventListener('change', function(){
 if (this.value === '5'){
   form.style.display = 'none';
 }
 else {
   form.style.display = 'block';
 }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="roomsForm">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomsNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, "Type of home", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = 'ddlProductCategory" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DimitarGanichev Check out this codepen (http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/LERapz). If you select the item 5 the form hides. I have parse the razor to html but anyway the example should help you.